# move semantics inside assignment operator - side effects, destruction

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

[Forcing Move Semantics](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_04.html)

> So in a sense, we have drifted into the netherworld of
>   non-deterministic destruction here: a variable has been assigned to,
>   but the object formerly held by that variable is still out there
>   somewhere. **That's fine as long as the destruction of that object does
>   not have any side effects that are visible to the outside world.** But
>   sometimes destructors do have such side effects. An example would be
>   the release of a lock inside a destructor. Therefore, any part of an
>   object's destruction that has side effects should be performed
>   explicitly in the rvalue reference overload of the copy assignment
>   operator:

```
X& X::operator=(X&& rhs)
{

  // Perform a cleanup that takes care of at least those parts of the
  // destructor that have side effects. Be sure to leave the object
  // in a destructible and assignable state.

  // Move semantics: exchange content between this and rhs

  return *this;
}
```

I get that l-value's original object normally is destructed - eventually - in a NON-assignment situation.

**But, in an assignment operator, why would you want the same behavior?**

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @KerrekSB the line in bold.

Comment: Consider `unique_ptr<T>`; if you have 2 of those, and you move assign one to the other, wouldn't you want the destination `unique_ptr<T>` to delete the `T` it owns before it assumes ownership of the source `T`?

Comment: @Praetorian but aren't you just swapping `T`s ? So the rhs would just assume responsibility no?

Comment: You could implement it that way, but why would you? Assignment doesn't have the same semantic meaning as swap, and most people will not expect your assignment operator to behave that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to do your chores: you are responsible to modify the old object into a (safe) destructible state (and if you are nice, then even to a generaly valid object state). There is cost to everything (even move semantics).

E.g. for a typical vector implementation:

```
V& V::operator=(V&& old){
    auto trash = this->data;
    this->data = old.data;

    //cleanup
    delete[] trash;
    old.data = nullptr; // expecting delete[] of the destructor of old
}
```

You paid three extra assignments (can be optimalized away with a single `swap()` trick ) and minor inconvenience to yourself. You avoided like perhaps 10000 asignments. Worth it, no?

Also if you use dangerous side-effects in destructors (which you shouldn't), this won't be the only problem you encounter. You can also disable your move assignment, if you consider it dangerous for your class.

Comment: why can't you just swap ownership? Why can't `V&& old` just assume ownership of the resources of the lhs?

Comment: @Adrian that is one way you can do it

Comment: @vu1p3n0x well I'm trying to understand if there are multiple valid ways to do it lol.

Comment: `Also if you use dangerous side-effects in destructors (which you shouldn't)` - the original source says having side-effects in destructors is fine: "That's fine as long as the destruction of that object does not have any side effects that are visible to the outside world. But sometimes destructors do have such side effects. An example would be the release of a lock inside a destructor."

Comment: I said **dangerous** side-effects. E.g. dynamic memory the object owns is fine (as in the example).

Comment: Also you can swap ownership. That's exactly the `swap()` trick I mentioned. But it's safe/more robust to make the other object valid "empty" object - e.g. empty vector or "" string. Or at least something that will throw, if(=when) somebody misuses it.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the above paragraph more carefully, I 'saw' the answer: when you have side-effects in the destructor, you want to be able to control when those side-effects occur. If you don't explicitly destruct the original lhs object in the assignment operator, then you have no direct control over when its destructor gets called; adding some code later might extend the life of that object. Why does it matter? Like the link says, if your object is just data like `Queue<int>`, then who cares when it gets destructed. But if your object holds a lock or some other resource that affects other objects, then you want the release of said resources to be deterministic.

Comment: Let me know if the answer should be re-worded. I know I basically re-worded the link's paragraph but for me it helped to understand.

Comment: You overthink it. Move assignment is first and formost a optimization of copy assignment and as such there should be no outside semantic/behavior difference between them (unless you have reasons - like excessive optimization like the `swap()` implementation style and exploiting the `b` for garbage processing). Actually the article is wrong, because the same applies to copy assignment. Instead of destroying the resources of `a`, you could pass it instead to some garbage collection pool to be deleted later.